# Select from all tables inside the schema containing column with name

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

How can I get select (table_name, table_name.age)?
I need to get values from column 'age' from all tables having this column/

I have this function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION union_all_tables()
 RETURNS TABLE
  (
    age   bigint
  ) AS
$$
DECLARE
 dynamic_query text = '';
 r_row         record;
BEGIN
FOR r_row IN SELECT table_schema || '.' || table_name qualified_table_name
       FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
       WHERE column_name = 'age' 
LOOP
dynamic_query := dynamic_query || format('UNION SELECT ' ||                                      
                                       'age ' ||
                                       'FROM %s ',r_row.qualified_table_name) || E'\n'; -- adding new line for pretty print, it    is not necessary
END LOOP;

dynamic_query := SUBSTRING(dynamic_query, 7) || ';';

RAISE NOTICE 'Union all tables in staging, executing statement: %',    dynamic_query;
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE dynamic_query;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Problems like this are typically caused by a poor table design.

Comment: How can I return table_name as well as column values?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to generate a single huge UNION statement. If you use `RETURN QUERY` the result of that query is appended to the overall result of the function every time you use it.

When dealing with dynamic SQL you should also use `format()` to properly deal with identifiers.

Your function can be simplified to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION union_all_tables()
 RETURNS TABLE (table_schema text, table_name text, age bigint) 
AS
$$
DECLARE
 dynamic_query text = '';
 r_row         record;
BEGIN
  FOR r_row IN SELECT c.table_schema, c.table_name
               FROM information_schema.columns c
               WHERE c.column_name = 'age' 
  LOOP
    dynamic_query := format(
                      'select %L as table_schema, %L as table_name, age from %I.%I', 
                           r_row.table_schema, r_row.table_name, 
                           r_row.table_schema, r_row.table_name);
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE dynamic_query;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Note that the whole function will fail if there is (at least) one table where the `age` column is not a `bigint`.